# Not able to connect Elasticsearch docker container running on different port

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana, iptables

I have a elasticsearch 7.6.1 docker container which i want to run on port 9400,9500 port.

This is the docker run command I have used.

```
docker run -d --name elasticsearch761v2  -v /data/dump/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data 

-p 9400:9400 -p 9500:9500 -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch:7.6.1
```

Which gives the below output.

```
docker ps -a | grep elastic
idofcontainer        elasticsearch:7.6.1                        "/usr/local/bin/docke"   18 minutes ago      Up 4 minutes                     

9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9400->9400/tcp, 9300/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9500->9500/tcp   elasticsearch761v2
```

I have also set the elasticsearch.yml setting to below.

```
[root@idofcontainer config]# vi elasticsearch.yml
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
transport.tcp.port: 9400
```

I have added Iptable entry for the above ports too.

The log for this container is :-

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-04-06T08:25:22,684Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "4196b5b23",
"message": "Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[.kibana_task_manager_1][0], [.kibana_1][0]]]).", "cluster.uuid": "gx7s8R_PTUK4lFPPGBZA", "node.id": "XfLZnNNnQnAOHJnWdDQg"  }
```

The Curl output is this :-

```
curl http://eserver:9400/_cat
This is not an HTTP port
```

Because of this, my kibana is also not able to reach the ES server.
I have set the kibana.yml to point to the above port.

Kibana.yml

```
# Default Kibana configuration for docker target
server.name: kibana
server.host: "0"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://eserver:9400/"]
xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: true
```

The log of this kibana container.

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-04-06T08:49:14Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":7,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://eserver:9400/"}

{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-04-06T08:49:14Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":7,"message":"No living connections"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have defined custom transport port `9400` and using it as HTTP port in your `curl` command to check the Elastic server, which error message is clearly pointing.

> This is not an HTTP port

As you mentioned, you want to run your Elastic on 9400 and 9500, then you need to properly **bind the default HTTP port 9200** to 9500, using below command.

```
docker run -d --name elasticsearch761v2  -v /data/dump/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data 

-p 9400:9400 -p 9500:9200 -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch:7.6.1
```

**Note the only change required is `-p 9500:9200` and after that, you can check your ES server using `curl http://eserver:9500` , ie using HTTP port.**

Comment: Hey thanks, I did realize that right after posting the question I  changed the port right after i realised it, your answer is right. Thanks :)

Comment: can you have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61079243/elasticsearch-reindex-elasticsearch-dump-does-not-copy-all-fields-of-the-source