# Elasticsearch _reindex/elasticsearch-dump does not copy all fields of the source index

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex

I have an index in elasticsearch 6.x, I want to copy this index to new elastic search 7.

I tried using  `elasticsearch-dump:v6.24.0` & `_reindex` api. I was able to copy the data from the source index, but not all the fields/properties are getting fully copied. It seems to skip few of them.

where am I going wrong ?

This is the _reindex request.

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://prodsystem:9200"

    },
    "index": "file",
    "query": {
      "match_all": {}
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "filebkp"
  }
}
```

Comment: "not all the fields are copied" & "skip few of them" are pretty vague statements. Can you provide more insights into what is going on and what you expect?

Comment: there are around 32 subfields in one of field of the index, when i reindexed it to another cluster, that field had only 20 subfields. I expect all of the 32 subfields to be copied.

Comment: add the mapping of your target and the mapping your source. moreover add one document from the source and the corresponding of the target

Answer (score 1):

Use elasticsearchdump to dump your's mapping, settings and data of old elasticsearch. After use elasticsearchdump again to restore data to new elasticsearch.
https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump